# How to create a difference score for Neo4j nodes with matching properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a difference count between files that have a matching number of hashes. The node labels being matched are QueryBlock and RegisterBlock.

I would like to establish this the total number of hashes for both the QueryBlock and RegisterBlock nodes and the number of the matching hashes. Then subtract the number of matching hashes from the Total Register Hashes to give the difference

```
TotalRegisterHashes TotalQueryHashes  TotalMatchingHashes   Difference
1400                400               400                   1000
```

I am running this query:

```
//Match QueryFiles to RegisterFiles using Block Hash Matches
MATCH (m:QueryBlock),(p:RegisterBlock)
WHERE m.qBlockHash = p.rBlockHash
RETURN 
    COUNT(p) AS TotalRegisterHashes, 
    COUNT(m) AS TotalQueryHashes,   
    COUNT(*) AS TotalMatchingHashes, 
    abs((COUNT(p) - COUNT(*))) AS Difference
```

And the response:

```
TotalRegisterHashes TotalQueryHashes    TotalMatchingHashes     Difference
793                 793                 793                     0
```

The `TotalMatchingHashes` is correct but the others are not. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your `count()` functions, you're running them after the filtering has already taken place, so there's no way that's going to give you the totals for the nodes before you filtered. You should calculating the totals first. Getting the count of all nodes of a label is an optimized operation, using a precomputed total rather than actually having to count the nodes in the db. After you get the totals for the given labels, then do the rest of your query for the matching hashes and the difference.

```
//Match QueryFiles to RegisterFiles using Block Hash Matches
MATCH (m:QueryBlock)
WITH COUNT(m) AS TotalQueryHashes
MATCH (p:RegisterBlock)
WITH TotalQueryHashes, COUNT(p) AS TotalRegisterHashes
MATCH (m:QueryBlock),(p:RegisterBlock)
WHERE m.qBlockHash = p.rBlockHash
WITH TotalRegisterHashes, TotalQueryHashes, COUNT(*) AS TotalMatchingHashes
RETURN  TotalRegisterHashes, 
        TotalQueryHashes, 
        abs(TotalRegisterHashes - TotalMatchingHashes) AS Difference
```

Comment: How can this display the resulting numbers with 5 decimal places?

Comment: That requires [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_number_format_conversions).